# What happens to existing awaits when WebSocket.close is called

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, fastapi, starlette

If I open a Starlette/FastAPI WebSocket, what happens to any coroutines currently waiting to receive data from the client if I close the WebSocket from outside the coroutine? Does the call to `receive` raise an exception or does the coroutine sit in memory forever because it is never going to receive anything?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.websockets import WebSocket

app = FastAPI()

open_sockets = {}

@app.websocket('/connection/')
async def connection(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    id = await websocket.receive_json()['id']
    open_sockets[id] = websocket

    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_json()

@app.post('/kill/{id}/')
async def kill(id=str):
    # What does this do to the above `await websocket.receive_json()`?
    await open_sockets[id].close()
    del open_sockets[id]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It raises a `starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect` with code 1006

```
  File ".\websocket_close_test.py", line 27, in connection
    data = await websocket.receive_json()
  File "C:\Apps\Python38\lib\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 98, in receive_json
    self._raise_on_disconnect(message)
  File "C:\Apps\Python38\lib\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 80, in _raise_on_disconnect
    raise WebSocketDisconnect(message["code"])
```

I did note that the .close() call blocked for a little while.

Here's the code I used to test, the second `ws.send` was never received.

```py
import time

import requests
import websocket

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://localhost:8000/connection/")
print('Sending id 0')
ws.send('{ "id": "0" }')
time.sleep(2)
print('Closing id 0')
requests.post('http://localhost:8000/kill/0/')
print('id 0 is closed')
time.sleep(2)
print('Trying to send data on closed connection')
ws.send('{ "id": "10" }')
```